# Pseudo Elements - best practice to "over-ride" the parent of a pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to add the href of a link after the link using a pseudo-element but not keep the parent's text-decoration. The code below shows "a" and "a:after" having different text-decoration.

```
a 
{
text-decoration: none;
color:#000000;
}

a:after 
{
content:  attr(href);
color:#999999;
text-decoration: underline;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Even though the text-decoration is set differently both "a great link" and "www.stackoverflow.com" have the same text-decoration. (See below)

**`<a href="wwww.stackoverflow.com">`a great link`</a>`   wwww.stackoverflow.com**

Changing the text-decoration of the pseudo-element doesn't work as it's specificity is 1. The only way I can solve the problem is by adding a span to the link itself.

```
.underline-kludge
{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

**`<a href="wwww.stackoverflow.com"><span class="underline-kludge">`a great link`</span></a>`   wwww.stackoverflow.com**

I'm not happy with this solution. Is there a better way? Do I have to add spans to links to solve this problem?

EDIT - EDIT - EDIT

I would like like the pseudo class (a:after) to have a different text-decoration than the parent.  I can't do an over-ride of the parent text-decoration using css alone.  The only way I see how to do it is by adding a span which I would rather not do.

Comment: So.. what do you want the end result to be? The `a` underlined, but the `:after` content not underlined..?

Comment: You don't need that `span` -- adding `class="underline-kludge"` to the `a` tag works just as cleanly.

Comment: Your examples are not illustrative here, you better provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces your issue

Comment: Looking at the example I gave I can see that it's confusing.  It's less important which is underlined than coming up with a solution that doesn't require adding spans to the html.

Comment: Something looks mixed up here. Your initial css declares that the link itself should have no text-decoration but the href after the link should have an underline and it works just like that. But then the span solution you are offering forces an underline for the link also making them both the same?

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/MAYO/Saj2x/4/

Comment: The question (including the title) should be rewritten so that it clearly states the problem. The question should be self-contained and understandable without reading a thread of comments.

Comment: You aren't explaining yourself very well. If the text is to be NOT underlined but the href IS see: http://jsfiddle.net/Cyu78/ No span required.

Comment: OK. Will come up with another question - that is better phrased. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a really good question - it stumped me for a while.

Simply set `display:inline-block` on the `:after` pseudo element, therefore allowing `text-decoration:none` to take effect; and thus not be overwritten.

[**Working jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tmHdf/)

---

[**See a example without**](http://jsfiddle.net/cDK83/) `display:inline-block` - you will notice the problem.

Comment: That was it. Thx. I hated the idea of using spans.